# Save new foreign key with django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two models:

```
class Studio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Studio", max_length=30, unique=True)

class Film(models.Model):
    studio = models.ForeignKey(Studio, verbose_name="Studio")
    name = models.CharField("Film Name", max_length=30, unique=True)
```

I have a Film form that allows the user to either select a preexisting Studio, or type in a new one:

```
class FilmForm(forms.Form):
    studio = forms.ModelChoiceField(Studio.objects, required=False)
    new_studio = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, label = "New Studio Name")
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label = "Film Name")
```

There's validation to assure that the new_studio name doesn't already exist.  If the user enters a new_studio, I want to save the studio and then save the new Film.

```
form = FilmForm(request.POST) 
if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
    std = Studio(name = form.cleaned_data['new_studio'])
    std.save()
```

But then how do I save the Film instance subject to the brand new studio id?  I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953206/django-foreign-key-save), but what if I have many more fields in the Film model and Film Form?  If I use the linked answer, I would have to enter each field:

```
studio = Studio.objects.get(name=request.POST['new_studio'])
newFilm=Film(name=form.name, studio=studio, field_one = form.field_one, field_two = form.field_two, etc.)
```

What is the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really, your only problem is that you've used a standard `Form` instead of a `ModelForm`. `Form` doesn't have a `save` method because it's not inherently tied to anything (i.e. it doesn't know what to save or where to save to).

However, if you use a `ModelForm` you need to take care of all logic involved in creating a new studio in the form. This is actually better, though, because then you can just use the form and not worry about anything else: the form holds all the logic needed to properly save itself.

```
class FilmForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Film

    # only need to define `new_studio`, other fields come automatically from model
    new_studio = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, label = "New Studio Name")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FilmForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # make `studio` not required, we'll check for one of `studio` or `new_studio` in the `clean` method
        self.fields['studio'].required = False

    def clean(self):
        studio = self.cleaned_data.get('studio')
        new_studio = self.cleaned_data.get('new_studio')
        if not studio and not new_studio:
            # neither was specified so raise an error to user
            raise forms.ValidationError('Must specify either Studio or New Studio!')
        elif not studio:
            # get/create `Studio` from `new_studio` and use it for `studio` field
            studio, created = Studio.objects.get_or_create(name=new_studio)
            self.cleaned_data['studio'] = studio

        return super(FilmForm, self).clean()
```

Then, in your view, all you need is:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Comment: oh, hmm. Nice!  I thought I had to go the long way around to compensate for the possibility of adding a new studio.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm having one issue though.  I created a validation check for a duplicate studio (if a user enters a new_studio that already exists).  The code correctly reaches the ValidationError, but seems to continue to clean anyway and gives me the error: Cannot assign None: "Film.studio" does not allow null values.

Comment: The `clean` method takes care of all that. If the `new_studio` exists, it will simply get the exisiting studio instead of actually creating a new one (`get_or_create`), so the validation check you have is unnecessary. The only case not covered by the `clean` method above is if `studio` is entered but `new_studio` is not. However, that wouldn't be an error and nothing special needs to be done in that scenario. I imagine whatever validation check you're doing is messing with the values somehow.

Comment: gotcha.  but when leaving both studio and new_studio blank and after removing that duplicate-check, I'm still getting the error.  Revised question here if you care to comment?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010852/catching-validation-errors-in-django-forms

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this question and I think I got a better answer for future seekers.

Django comes with something called [Inline Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) which helps you manage relationships in a form.

You just have to create your model like you did with their respective ForeignKeys.
Then in the Forms.py import this

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
```

Then:

```
YOUR_FORMSET = inlineformset_factory(Model1,Model2)
```

Back on yout views.py you should import both your Form and your new created YOUR_FORMSET.

After doing this, your method should use the inlineformset like this:

```
def add_question(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':


      form =AddQuestionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
          new_question = form.save(commit=False)

          question_formset = QuestionFormset(request.POST, instance=new_question)
          if question_formset.is_valid():
              form.save()
              question_formset.save()
              return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:detail',args=(new_question.pk,)))
      else:
          print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = AddQuestionForm()
        question_formset = QuestionFormset(instance=Question())
    return render(request, 'polls/add.html', {'form':form, 'question_formset':question_formset,})
```

I'm using my own example but the idea is explained.

If you want to read a more specific explication read this awesome [blog post](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/djangos-inlineformsetfactory-and-you/) that I found.

Comment: Hope it helps more people :)

Comment: the link gives 404

Comment: Link to the Inline Formsets doc in Django 3.2 : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets